# GreenDAO creating an automatic ID property

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

is there a way to make the DB create the ID property in an automatic way?

I want to generate something that looks like this:

```
Entity entity = schema.addEntity("MyEntity");
entity.addIdProperty().autoIncrement().primaryKey();
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that looks just fine. Depending on your needs entity.addIdProperty() or entity.addIdProperty().autoIncrement() should be fine. addIdProperty will already call primaryKey().

Comment: does this mean that inserting into the DB will create an id automatically?

Comment: The correct way is: tipo.addIdProperty().autoincrement();